# Static files from node module for client

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, socket.io

Im making a module for node.js and it is meant to serve javascript on the server side (like most nodejs modules) but also needs to enable a javascript file to be shared with a client (browser).

The client is served by an express server, dealing with the routes.

However I can't seem to find a way to server the javascript file from the node module, as a static file (without it having to, either be placed to a static folder by the user or having to parse the app as parameter to the module).

These are two posibilities that I'd like to avoid, as I noticed Socket.IO does not take these steps to share its socket.io-client code.

I looked into their code, to look in how they did it but can't seem to find it.

So I am wondering what the best way is, to share a static javascript file to a client from a node module.

Comment: Please add method to use your module, example use with `express`, `http`, etc

Comment: As stated, im not using express in the module at the moment, as that is not the way I hope to make it possible.